# How to stop div with long string of content from "hanging off" other divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/vrodomista/pen/QEmdzR)

HTML:

```
<div id="splash" class="divider">
  <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">vincent/rodomista</h1>
  <p class="text-center text uppercase">Full Stack Web Developer</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#splash {
    background: gray;
    height: 75%;
}

#splash h1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 6em;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

#splash p {
    font-size: 5em;
    color: white;
}
.divider {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60%;
    display: table;
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple personal website to teach myself CSS, but have been struggling with one problem. The first div that I have, upon shrinking the screen to medium or small, seems to "hang off" of the divs below it - in that it is longer than the others. I suspect this is because the text contained in it is not being properly wrapped. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrapping won't help you much since the name is an uninterrupted string of characters. While you may not be comfortable enough to make it fully responsive, it would definitely help to decrease the font-size of the splash whenever the viewport gets smaller.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @Shane - however, my answer is a direct answer to the question, not so much a design/philosophy recommendation.

Comment: @Shane what is the best way to go about shrinking the font size? Bootstrap? I'm willing to learn how to make it responsive.

Comment: @VincentRodomista Check out: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints You could add something like: `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { #splash h1 { font-size: 2em; } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two choices - you can hide the text as the div shrinks by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element, or you can use the `word-break` CSS property:

`word-break: break-word;`

On your text elements.

More info:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/